# Oracle Left Join causing single-row subquery returns more than one row error

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

Not sure why this code is not working -- seems to be a relatively easy join.

```
select *
FROM VIEW_DB.VIEW1 VC0
LEFT OUTER JOIN VIEW_DB.VIEW2 VC1
ON TRIM(VC0.STRING_DATE) = TO_CHAR(VC1.CALENDAR_DAY, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

In the example VC0.STRING_DATE is a field that contains varchar data, example of Jan 1 2020 would be: "01/01/2020                  " (added quotes to show the white space).

Calendar Day is a date field.

Goal is to join the string dates to date field with the left outer join intact. With an INNER join this works fine.

**Additional Notes**

VIEW1 -- is simply a 1:1 view of a staging table. STRING_DATE is stored as a VARCHAR(100). I have no choice in this matter. We are hoping to eliminate this issue with better ETL mapping but currently this is what we are stuck with.

VIEW2 -- CAL_DT is a DATE column. Produced by: TRUNC(to_date('2020/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') -1  + N.n) as CAL_DT

Comment: Show us the view definitions...

Comment: I don't see how this could would raise the *single-row subquery returns more than one row* error.

Comment: care to share column types and if they're VARCHAR2, formats ? I smell a trunc() or two may be need.

Comment: The query looks okay. The error must be in one of the views.

Comment: @jarlh I have added additional details.

Comment: You will have to show us the views, if you want us to point you to the error in them.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference whether to use an inner or outer join, by the way. Maybe your tool just shows some rows and you'll have to scroll to the end in order to load more rows and force the error to happen.

Comment: I cannot  share the view as its 274 lines and contains sensitive details. I appreciate the help but I may need to track it down myself. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Okay that shouldn't be too difficult anyway. Look out for subqueries that are compared with a single value, e.g. `where (select ...) > 5` or used in the select or order by clause, e.g. `select a, b, (select ...) as c from ...`. Then check whether these subqueries are guaranteed to return a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the value, but on only one side:

```
SELECT *
FROM VIEW_DB.VIEW1 VC0 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     VIEW_DB.VIEW2  VC1
     ON TO_DATE(VC0.STRING_DATE, 'MMM DD YYYY') = VC1.CALENDAR_DAY;
```

Of course, this might generate a type conversion error.  That is a good thing.  You should learn how to store values using the correct data type.  And a string is not the correct data type for a date.

Comment: what if CV1.CALENDAR_DAY has hours and seconds as well ?

Comment: @BigMike: Then CALENDAR_**DAY** is a very bad name :-) Too bad that Oracle doesn't have a real `DATE` data type, but only a datetime type they *call* DATE.

Comment: I have updated my notes -- this design is not by choice. The main hang up I have is why does this work with an INNER but not a LEFT. This is some kind of Oracle specific issue as I this will work in Teradata.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner that's why I prefer to add an explicit TRUNC(date_column) when comparing, Ofc if you know time part is always 00:00:00, you can skip the trunc